# Ruby sprintf acting up in 1.9

Tags: ruby, encoding, printf

I am experiencing some confusion on the `Kernel#sprintf` method in Ruby.

Ruby 1.9 handles encoding in a different way than Ruby 1.8.

Here are the results I am after, and how it behaves in Ruby 1.8:

```
>> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.8.7"
>> sprintf("%c", 88599)
=> "\027"
```

This is how it behaves in Ruby 1.9:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.9.3" 
1.9.3p194 :002 > sprintf("%c", 88599)
=> "\u{15A17}"
```

If I use the magic comment to set the encoding to binary (ascii-8bit) I get an error:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.9.3" 
1.9.3p194 :002 > # encoding: binary
1.9.3p194 :003 >   sprintf("%c", 88599)
RangeError: 88599 out of char range
from (irb):3:in `sprintf'
from (irb):3
from /Users/lisinge/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

I have also tried this with Ruby 1.9.2 so there doesn't seem to be specific to 1.9.3.

Maybe I am doing something wrong? I am not so familiar with the `Kernel#sprintf` method.

I am using a smpp library called ruby-smpp which can be found on [github](https://github.com/raykrueger/ruby-smpp). It is the [`send_concat_mt`](https://github.com/raykrueger/ruby-smpp/blob/master/lib/smpp/transceiver.rb#L47) method on line #47 that is acting up when i am trying to run it in Ruby 1.9.3.

I would greatly appreciate it if any of you could shed some light on this matter.

Comment: It probably starts supporting Unicode, hence the behavior. I don't think you should rely on the this "feature" of `sprintf`.

Comment: Yeah, we can see that in my examples.
And you dont thick that i should rely on a method in ruby stdlib of which's documentation says the same in both versions?

As i am saying in my question it seems like i am doing something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sprintf documentation states:

```
Field |  Other Format 
------+--------------------------------------------------------------
  c   | Argument is the numeric code for a single character or
      | a single character string itself.
```

88599 is not a valid numeric code for a single character in the default behavior for Ruby 1.8; which, I believe, is no encoding.  What it appears to be doing is doing a mod 256 on the value you supply and then converting it:

```
% irb
1.9.3-p194 :003 > 88599 % 256 == 027
 => true
```

As to you doing something wrong, no.  What did happen is that allowing out-of-bounds character codes was a bug that has been fixed by Ruby 1.9 which now properly throws an exception.